# Why this simple HelloWorld jQuery JSFiddle not working

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

Am quite new to JSFiddle and I know I may miss something. Just want to know why this simple Hello World jQuery JSFiddle not working

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Mahesha999/CpnYW/1/

The code is as below for reference

**HTML**

```
<div id="div9" ></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("div9").text("Hello World!!!");
```

I specified jQuery 1.10.1 with `onDomready`

Comment: You need `#` to specify an ID.  Ex:  `$("#div9").text("Hello World!!!");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are missing `#`  *id selector*

```
$("#div9").text("Hello World!!!");
```

Demo `----->` http://jsfiddle.net/CpnYW/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), starts with `#`

it should be

```
$("#div9").text("Hello World!!!");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5sX96/)

Your selector `div9` is an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), it looks for an element with tag `div9`. ex `<div9></div9>`